# Set Label HeightRequest automatically depending on how much space the text needs

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, height, uwp

I have a `Label` inside a `StackLayout` inside a `Frame`:

```
<Frame Grid.Row="0" Margin="0, 0, -10, 0" OutlineColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource rightBubbleColor}">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label
      Style="{StaticResource rightBubbleStyle}"
      TextColor="{StaticResource rightBubbleFontColor}"
      Text="{Binding message}" />
  </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

This gives me this result:

[image: Label without HeightRequest]

The problem here is that the last message actually has more text which would need 6 rows to display the whole text.

If I set a value for `HeightRequest` for the `Label`, it changes the height of the `Frame` as well. For example if I set a value of 150, I get this result:

[image: Label with HeightRequest]

I need to dynamically set a value for `HeightRequest` depending on how much height the `Text` needs.

Does anyone know how I can achieve that (preferably in xaml) or is this even a wrong approach to my problem?

### Edit 1:

Removing the style from the `Label` doesn't solve the problem. It only occurs on UWP. Note that I don't have a Windows Phone to test it, the problem occurs on my local machine (Windows 10 Desktop).

### Edit 2:

According to the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/), the height *should* be autosized dependon on the content:

> When the app developer sets the ListView.HasUnevenRows property to true, the behavior of the list view still depends on the ListView.RowHeight property. First, if the developer either does not set the ListView.RowHeight property or sets it to -1, list view items are autosized to fit their contents. This is the desired behavior and the intended use case for a ListView.HasUnevenRows value of true, as noted above.

Comment: I made a basic demo. But didn't reproduce your problem. The Label changes it's height according to the text volume automatically. Could you please post the complete XAML codes along with the style?

Comment: @Evlis thank you. Did you test this for UWP? It works on Android and iOS for me as well, but not on UWP.

Comment: Yes I tested it on UWP. So I guess something else is clipping the label.

Comment: @Elvis I've edited my question. The style is not the problem

Comment: Then could you please try the codes on a blank empty xamarin project?

Comment: Great, Happy to know this problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. This was the problem:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
```

I set the value to `Auto` and now it's working. Strange that it has a different behaviour on iOS and Android tho.